# Should I remind a recruiter to call

Tags: recruitment

A recruiter told me that he would call tomorrow.  It is now tomorrow, and I haven't received a call yet.  Do you think it's best to write him an email saying:

> I am now at home, and will be available all day.  Feel free to give me a call at any time at your convenience.

Is this a polite way of wording this, and would you recommend me to say this?

Thanks

Comment: I wouldnt worry too much yet. Unless that was a very critical call.

Comment: Remind him the next day. He might have planned to call you in the end of the afternoon, unless the call is of critical importance you don't need to push him.

Answer (score 1):

Wait one more day to call him.

Although it might seem like a good idea to show him you're really interested, you don't want to appear to eager, especially by calling back too soon (he might have planned to call you later in the day).

And if tomorrow, he doesn't answer, leave a message on his answering machine, something like :

> Hi, it's *[Name]* from *[Company]*,
>
> I was wondering if you had any news concerning *[Position]*, in which
>   I'm still very interested.
>
> You can reach me all day today at *[Phone number]*, please feel free to
>   give me a call when you get this message.
>
> I'm looking forward to hearing from you.

Don't remind him he said he'd call you the day before, just act like you're waiting for his call but don't rush him.

Answer (score 0):

**It'll depend on your schedules** 
If you are free to attend their call at any time then I would recommend 
As earlier answers suggests to wait a day and then remind them to not to rush things.

And if you have hectic schedule later on then I would recommend you to remind them as early as possible as you feel easy.
Although it will show you as an eager candidate but it has a good effect too it'll show that you sincerely interested in getting the job.